# How to fork 30 connections in Perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a monitoring script to login to the database, perform tasks, and logout. I have 30 accounts to the database. But I would like my Perl script to perform this task with 30 simultaneous logins and presently my loop has it that one iteration has to finish before the other can start.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;

 foreach my $i ( "01" .. "30" ) {
 do stuff...
 }
```

Comment: Fork 30 copies, one per account?

Comment: @Shawn If that is the correct terminology, then yes.

Comment: Your database needs to allow that many connections from your user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way, depending on what else your script might need to do, is to just fork itself 30 times, each copy processing one account.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw/:sys_wait.h/;

my $nchildren = 0;
$SIG{"CHLD"} = sub { while (waitpid(-1, WNOHANG) > 0) { $nchildren -= 1; } };

for my $i ( "01" .. "30" ) {
  my $pid = fork;
  if (! defined $pid) {
    die "Unable to fork: $!\n";
  } elsif ($pid == 0) {
     # Do stuff for account $i
     exit 0; # And exit.
  } else {
    $nchildren += 1;
  }
}

# Wait for all child processes to exit.
while ($nchildren > 0) {
  sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: No need for the signal handler; just use `while ($children) { wait; --$children }` instead of the bottom loop